# Wordpress administrator area access disabled temporarily due to widespread brute force attacks

Tags: admin, user-access

My wordpress site admin side return this error. 'Wordpress administrator area access disabled temporarily due to widespread brute force attacks'. Can't access the site. Any one have similar experience please share here.

Yes i got it.

Unfortunately wordpress websites are being attacked by hackers using bruteforce technique. Please add following to your .htaccess file in wp installation folder and replace x.x.x.x with your IP from which you want to access admin area.

```
<Files ~ "^wp-login.php"> 
Order deny,allow 
Deny from all 

Allow from x.x.x.x 
</Files>
```

Comment: That's not a WordPress message. Contact your hoster.

Comment: But site is working fine. only admin area have this problem. I mean /wp-admin or /wp-login.php

Comment: You mean i need to ask to the hoster for this? ok thanks for your support.

Comment: Ask your host for details. There is a large Brute Force attack on WordPress websites right now. [Link](http://blog.sucuri.net/2013/04/protecting-against-wordpress-brute-force-attacks.html)

Comment: Where is your site hosted? GigeNET?

Comment: "There is a large Brute Force attack..."-- yes, indeed there is